# Interpolate NA values in one variable while using linear interpolant

Tags: r, interpolation

Trying to interpolate NA values in a dataframe, and tried using the `zoo::na.approx` but this just returns equally spaced values.

To demonstrate, given the dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo) 
df <- data.frame(
      a = c(1,5 ,6 , 10),
      b = c(100, NA, NA, 1000)
)
```

Tried this:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(b = zoo::na.approx(b, rule = 2))
```

Instead wanted to get this:

```
desired_df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 5 ,6 , 10),
  b = c(100, 500, 600, 1000)
)
```

Is there a readily available function to do this, or it has to be written using the linear interpolation formula:

[image]

Comment: I posted an answer using `zoo`. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is available in `zoo`:

```
desired_df <- as.zoo(df, order.by = df$a) %>% 
  na.approx()
```

As you can see, you needed to convert your data frame into `zoo` class.

Comment: This also works without conversion to zoo: `df %>% mutate(b = na.approx(b, a))` . The key point is that you have to have some way of telling it to interpolate relative to a.  If it is a zoo object whose time index is a then it knows; otherwise, you must tell it.

Answer (score 1):

```
lin_interp <- function(known, unknown) {
  # unknown object
  i1 <- !is.na(unknown)

  approx(x = known[i1], 
         y = unknown[i1], 
         xout = known)$y
}
```

to increase code readibility

The output is as desired:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(b = lin_interp(a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the code `na.approx` didn't work is because it dispatches methods by checking the class.  If we check

```
library(zoo)
methods('na.approx')
#[1] na.approx.default na.approx.ts*     na.approx.zoo*    na.approx.zooreg*
```

The method `na.approx.default` is the one applied on the OP's data as it is not a `zoo` object.  The behavior of these methods are different if we check the source code

```
na.approx.default
```

and for `*` functions

```
getAnywhere('na.approx.zoo')
```

So, as the other answer mentioned, if we convert to appropriate class, the output generated would be also different because the method dispatched is based on the `class`